Pivot when the snowflake table has more than 2 columns
I was trying to retrieve an output on Snowflake table having more than 2 columns to pivot. Below, sharing the code, expected output and the logics I have tried
create or replace table test(ID number, name1 varchar, value1 number, name2 varchar, value2 number)
    as select * from values
    (1, 'X1', 15, 'X2', 25),
    (1, 'X3', 45, 'X4', 65),
    (2, 'X1', 35, 'X2', 55),
    (2, 'X5', 85, 'X6', 95),
    (3, 'X7', 35, 'X8', 55);

Expected output is



ID
X1
X2
X3
X4
X5
X6
X7
X8




1
15
25
45
65
0
0
0
0


2
35
55
0
0
85
95
0
0


3
0
0
0
0
0
0
65
15



I tried the below 2 logics
1st Logic - this output is not doing GROUP BY on the ID column and creates NULLs
SELECT pvt1.*, pvt2.* (EXCLUDE pvt2.ID) FROM 
select pvt1.*, pvt2.* exclude ID from 
    (SELECT * EXCLUDE(name2,value2)
      FROM test
        PIVOT(MAX(value1) FOR name1 IN (ANY ORDER BY name1))
        ) pvt1 
  JOIN 
    (SELECT * EXCLUDE(name1,value1)
      FROM test
        PIVOT(MAX(value2) FOR name2 IN (ANY ORDER BY name2))
        ) pvt2 on pvt1.ID = pvt2.ID
        ;

2nd Logic - this output is generating the output but columns are not getting dynamically generated, I am hardcoding the column names(X1_COL, X2_COL) manually here
SELECT ID
, MAX(IFF(NAME1= 'X1',VALUE1,0)) AS X1_COl
, MAX(IFF(NAME2= 'X2',VALUE2,0)) AS X2_COL
, MAX(IFF(NAME1= 'X3',VALUE1,0)) AS X3_COL
, MAX(IFF(NAME2= 'X4',VALUE2,0)) AS X4_COL
, MAX(IFF(NAME1= 'X5',VALUE1,0)) AS X5_COL
, MAX(IFF(NAME2= 'X6',VALUE2,0)) AS X6_COL
, MAX(IFF(NAME1= 'X7',VALUE1,0)) AS X7_COL
, MAX(IFF(NAME2= 'X8',VALUE2,0)) AS X8_COL
FROM TEST GROUP BY ID;

Please assist with a better way to handle nulls and dynamically pick values from Name1 and Name2 of the table TEST as shown in the expected output

Write a subquery to turn your 5 columns in to three, then pivot like normal.

Using UNION ALL to unpivot and then dynamic PIVOT:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID, name1, value1 FROM test 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, name2, value2 FROM test
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
PIVOT(MAX(value1) FOR name1 IN (ANY ORDER BY name1) DEFAULT ON NULL (0)) pvt1; 

Output:

